# An unramified morphism of schemes iff the diagonal map is a local isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm reading *Neron Models* and am trying to understand the different equivalent definitions of a morphism of schemes being unramified.  I'm currently trying to understand the equivalence of (b) and (c).

[image]

The book says the equivalence of (b) and (c) follows directly from the definition of $\Omega_{X/S}$ and Nakayama's lemma.

Let's consider the affine case $S = \operatorname{Spec}R, A = \operatorname{Spec} X$.  Let $J$ be the kernel of the codiagonal $A \otimes_R A \rightarrow A$, so that $\Omega_{X/S} = J/J^2$ is naturally a module over $A = A\otimes_R A/J$.

Let $\mathfrak p \in X$ with preimage $\mathfrak P \in \operatorname{Spec} A\otimes_R A$.  Then the equivalence of (b) and (c) can be stated as:

> $(J/J^2)_{\mathfrak p} = 0$ if and only if $(A \otimes_R A)_{\mathfrak P} \rightarrow A_{\mathfrak p}$ is injective.

Maybe there is nothing special about the surjection $A \otimes_R A \rightarrow A$, and we can work more generally with a surjective ring homomorphism $\pi: B \rightarrow B/J$ with kernel $J$.  We need to assume $J$ is finitely generated.
The quotient $J/J^2$ is naturally a module over $B/J$.  Let $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak P/J$ be a prime of $B/J$.

To answer my question, it would be enough to show that $B_{\mathfrak P} \rightarrow (B/J)_{\mathfrak p}$ is injective if and only if $(J/J^2)_{\mathfrak p} = 0$.

This seems very strange.  Since $(B/J)_{\mathfrak p} = B_{\mathfrak P}/J_{\mathfrak P}$, the injectivity of this last homomorphism is equivalent to $J_{\mathfrak P} = 0$.  On the other hand, $$(J/J^2)_{\mathfrak p} = (J/J^2) \otimes_{B/J} ((B/J)/\mathfrak p) = J/J^2 \otimes_{B/J} B/\mathfrak P$$

Apparently this equivalence should fall out of Nakayama's lemma by tensoring with $B_{\mathfrak P}/\mathfrak PB_{\mathfrak P}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not agree with the first equation in your last equation environment. I guess you simply confused localization at an ideal with modding out by it for a moment. Viewing $(J/J^2)_{\mathfrak{p}}$ as a $B_{\mathfrak{P}}$-module, the equation should read:
$$
(J/J^2)_{\mathfrak{p}}=J/J^2 \otimes_{B/J} (B/J)_{\mathfrak{p}}=J/J^2 \otimes_{B/J} (B/J)_{\mathfrak{P}}=J/J^2\otimes_{B/J} (B/J\otimes_B B_{\mathfrak{P}})=(J/J^2)_{\mathfrak{P}}=J_{\mathfrak{P}}/J_{\mathfrak{P}}^2.
$$
Hence by Nakayama's Lemma, $(J/J^2)_{\mathfrak{p}}=0$ if and only if $J_{\mathfrak{P}}=0$.

By the way, (in case you were not aware of it) the finiteness condition on the ideal sheaf defining $X$ as a closed subscheme of some open in $X\times_S X$ is implied by the assumption on $f\colon X\to S$ being locally of finite presentation. Check out [Tag 0818, Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0818).

Comment: Thanks for answering.  So I'm having trouble with the implication $(J/J^2)_{\mathfrak p} = 0 \Rightarrow J_{\mathfrak P} = 0$.  I see that if $(J/J^2)_{\mathfrak p} = 0$, then $J_{\mathfrak P} = J_{\mathfrak P}^2$.  And you're saying by Nakayama's lemma, this cannot happen unless $J_{\mathfrak P} = 0$?

Comment: @D_S $J_{\mathfrak{P}}$ is contained in the maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $B_{\mathfrak{P}}=:R$, so that the equality $J_{\mathfrak{P}}=J_{\mathfrak{P}}^2$ implies $J_{\mathfrak{P}}=\mathfrak{m}J_{\mathfrak{P}}$. Since $M:=J_{\mathfrak{P}}$ is finitely generated, the equality $M=\mathfrak{m}M$ implies $M=0$ by Nakayama's Lemma.

Comment: I see, thank you.  Alternatively if $B_{\mathfrak P}$ is Noetherian, we can never have $J_{\mathfrak P} = J_{\mathfrak P}^2$ unless $J_{\mathfrak P} = 0$ by Krull intersection.